# PHP Can't download over 40MB weight files

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a simple file to download files.
I have the following code:

```
function DownloadFile($file) { // $file = include path
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK', true, 200);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

The problem is if I try to download files over 40-50MB the file is downloaded blank(0KB) but if I try below 40MB it is working perfectly.

What is the problem?

Comment: maybe this has to do with the use of php output buffer. Why do you have set it on ?

Comment: do you have the same issue with a minimum php file just downloading the file ?

Comment: Peirre because if not set, I get download refused(ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
). No, I don't have the same issue if I try to download files below 40MB

Comment: don't see why the download is refused if output buffering is off... never set it on, never had any issues

Comment: I am using wordpress

Comment: maybe because you come here with some issue, looking for advice, but ignore those advices. I suggested to test with a small php script. Still waiting.

Comment: Remove ob_clean, flush and set `@set_time_limit(0);` in the top.

Comment: Answers go in the answer section, not in your question post. I see you already posted it in the answer section, so thank you for that. Meta commentary on how the site works should not be part of posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*The solution:*

```
function DownloadFile($file) { // $file = include path
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK', true, 200);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

               ob_clean();
               flush();
               ob_end_flush();

            if ($fd = fopen ($file, "r")) {

                set_time_limit(0);
                ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

                while(!feof($fd)) {
                    echo fread($fd, 4096);
                    flush();
                }   

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like explained in this article https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/php-file-size-download-limit/6541 you need to set

```
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 300M
```

in php.ini file